# Does assigning a post request to a variable read all of its Reponse contents into memory?

Tags: post, memory, iterator, python-requests

Let's say we gave a generic POST request with Python's `requests`.

```py
req = requests.post('http://someapi.someservice.com', files=files)
```

`req` will be a Response object. In my case, the `.content` of the response can be very, very large so I do not wish to read it all into memory. Luckily, `requests` provides an iterator [`.iter_content`](https://2.python-requests.org//en/v0.10.6/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) that allows iteration over the contents. My question is, though, does `req` contain all contents of the response already (and as such everything is already read into memory), or does calling `.content` and as such `.iter_content` initiate a download which really fetches the content? This is important, because if assigning the POST request to a variable already reads the Response's content into memory, then of course using `.iter_content` makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the `stream` parameter to `True` in your request in order to avoid downloading the entire content of the response into the response object:

```
req = requests.post('http://someapi.someservice.com', files=files, stream=True)
```

Excerpt from the documentation of [Body Content Workflow](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow):

> By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is
>   downloaded immediately. You can override this behaviour and defer
>   downloading the response body until you access the `Response.content`
>   attribute with the `stream` parameter... You can further control the workflow by use of the `Response.iter_content()` and `Response.iter_lines()` methods.